# Authentication with Lambda and AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, amazon-cognito

After days of trial and error, I finally managed to get signin/signup working in VueJS with AWS Cognito. I have an idToken and accessToken and would like to pass that on to my Lambda function.

I read something about the API Gateway which has options for authentication, but there's no simple explanation how this all works together.

Any suggestions or hints how to move forward?

- Use aws-sdk within the function and somehow get the username/userid?
- Use the API Gateway to pass on the user before the function is invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Cognito User Pool makes it easy for developers to add sign-up and sign-in functionality to web and mobile applications. It serves as your own identity provider to maintain a user directory. It supports user registration and sign-in, as well as provisioning identity tokens for signed-in users as per doc

Now you have two options to configure Cognito pool with API getway

1) Use cognito authorizer : If you need to authantcate and authorize using Oauth.

2) Lambda custom authorizer : If you need custom IAM roles and Federated Identities or own logic.

Long story short here is you can find further detail:

- https://github.com/vaquarkhan/vaquarkhan/wiki/AWS-Custom-Lambda-authorizer---authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway-for-microservice

**Suggestions or hints**

Use aws-sdk within the function and somehow get the username/userid?

> You can use lambda authorizer and use sdk to get info if need custom logic based on user

Use the API Gateway to pass on the user before the function is invoked?

> Not clear ur question but as per my assumption - Cognito authorizer on api getway automatically takecare user id validation

Answer (score 1):

So Cognito authenicated the user. Great work!

Unfortunately there is no straight answer. Next, you need to answer how you plan to handle authorizing that user. You have a few options. One option that comes to mind is below.

1. Cognito provides IdentityPools in addition to user pools. You can use the identity pools to give the user access to do things. [AWS Cognito - Identity Pools documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/concepts.html)
2. The API gateway can check identitypool credentitials. [AWS API Gateway - Controlling access to gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html).